# How to iterate over a map while concurrently adding values to it?

Tags: java, concurrency, synchronization, iteration, concurrenthashmap

I'm holding a map of objects and each time an object is added to it all other objects in the map need to be notified of the new object and vice versa. These objects run on their own <strike>thread</strike> process (each one is started from a `main`) can can call a method which adds them to the map so an object can be added during iteration provoked from adding a previous object.

This is some example code I have. Here are the objects that I was talking about above

```
class Notifier {

    String name;
    Hub hub;

    Notifier(String name) {

        this.name = name;
        hub.add(this);
    }

    void acknowledge(String name) {

        System.out.println(this.name + " was notified of " + name);
    }
}
```

Here is the thing that holds the map

```
public class Hub {

    ConcurrentMap<String, Notifier> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    void add(Notifier notifier) {

        map.putIfAbsent(notifier.name, notifier);

        Iterator<Entry<String, Notifier>> it = map.entrySet().iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            Entry<String, Notifier> entry = it.next();
            if (!entry.getKey().equals(notifier.name)) {
                entry.getValue().acknowledge(notifier.name);
                notifier.acknowledge(entry.getKey());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I tried `ConcurrentHashMap` but it doesn't have to be that. My problem is that the results I get are each object is notified more than once about the other **if I launch their threads together**. I get

> notifier1 was notified of notifier2
>   notifier1 was notified of notifier2
>   notifier1 was notified of notifier3
>   notifier1 was notified of notifier3
>   notifier1 was notified of notifier4
>   notifier1 was notified of notifier4

and the same for the others. If I launch them 1 after the other so I let each finish adding I get the correct result

> notifier1 was notified of notifier2
>   notifier1 was notified of notifier3
>   notifier1 was notified of notifier4

and similar for the others.

I know that this map I chose makes no guarantee about updating the iterator when adding (putting) values so i think that's why it happens. Anyway I know there is some racing of the threads from the above experiment.

How do i make it so that each object is notified exactly 1 time of all others? Maybe this concurrent map is not good and I need to synchronize something? I don't care about the order of addings.

Comment: What sorts of objects are these? Is there a strong reason for making them independent threads rather than using a callback approach?

Comment: @chrylis it's like clients and a server. Each clients that comes in is notified of all other clients, and they are notified of it. isn't this a sort of callback already because the hub calls methods on the notifier object? sorry if I'm not understanding.

Comment: Sort of, but you specifically said that they "run on their own threads", which doesn't match the code you posted here.

Comment: @chrylis each one is launched separately through a `main`, so they are different applications. I thought it also means that they are on different threads.

Comment: Oh, then they're completely separate *processes*, which makes this a substantially different sort of question. Hmm.

Comment: The code you posted should work as expected. I think the problem is in other part of your app. Show us more or try to change map to list and I think you will see duplicates in your list.

Comment: @chrylis sorry, why is it different if they are processes or threads? they are all independent and can call `add` at their own time so the changes and iteration on the map needs to be synchronized/thread safe/process safe/whatever anyway, no?

Comment: Because multiple processes won't be sharing references to the actual same data structure. At most, they'll have independent copies that they try to keep in sync.

Comment: `changes and iteration on the map needs to be synchronized/thread safe/process safe/whatever anyway, no?`---Absolutely not. You have conflated entirely different levels of isolation.

Comment: @Max In a list I will see duplicates because it allows them. since i'm using `putIfAbsent` it's like a set, so no object is being iterated over more than 1 time.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik yes, but you send notifications anyway...

Comment: According to your current description, your code is actually single-threaded. Yet you're asking the question as if it were multithreaded. It has nothing to do with the problem as you've described it in the comments.

Comment: @Max After a couple of days of trying to recreate the problem to post here I found out that the conflict is with the main GUI thread which is not in the question. You are right the code does work if i disable the GUI. Sorry and thank you.

Comment: @chrylis  After a couple of days of trying to recreate the problem to post here I found out that the conflict is with the main GUI thread which is not in the question. If i disable the GUI it works. Sorry and thank you for explaining about the difference with the process and the thread.

Answer (score 0):

I think the error is pretty easy. You doesn't abort notification in case of duplicate notifier.

```
public class Hub {

    ConcurrentMap<String, Notifier> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    void add(Notifier notifier) {

        if (map.putIfAbsent(notifier.name, notifier) == null) {

            Iterator<Entry<String, Notifier>> it = map.entrySet().iterator();
            while (it.hasNext()) {
                Entry<String, Notifier> entry = it.next();
                if (!entry.getKey().equals(notifier.name)) {
                    entry.getValue().acknowledge(notifier.name);
                    notifier.acknowledge(entry.getKey());
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: But there are not multiple launches of of the same notifier - each calls the add method exactly once. I'll update my code, it seems that I'm on deeper water than I thought initially.

Comment: If you have several of them with the same name e.g. same key then map prevents duplicates but notifications are sent anyway.

Comment: i don't have several with the same name. The constructor is given a unique name.

Comment: As I said earlier show us more code. I've tried to guess what is wrong and failed, because without code it is rather tricky :)